# why does AVAudioPlayer only play some of my base64 files?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have a bunch of audio files on server with base64 encoded mp3 files
and AVAudioPlayer won't play them all. But I know there good files.

is there a better way to play files like this? whats the difference between 
AVAudioPlayer , AVPlayer, and if theres any other way to play files like this.

this is some code I am using

```
func playTrack(track: String) {
    do {
        let audioData: Data! = Data(base64Encoded: track, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters)
        //print(track)
        if audioData != nil {
            sound = try AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData)
            sound.play()
            print("is playing:", sound.isPlaying)
            print(sound.duration)
        }
        else {
            print("Data Not Exist")
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("didnt work 2")
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        // SHOW ALERT OR SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Probably unrelated to your issue, but: use `if let` to unwrap your optional `Data` in the third line, not `Data!`. Otherwise, you're going to crash whenever you encounter a bad file.

Comment: the error is much but doesn't crash. Unresolved error The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)

Comment: OSStatus 1954115647 is `kAudioFileStreamError_UnsupportedFileType`, so it would appear that the files are in a format that `AVAudioPlayer` can't read.

Comment: This site is great for looking these up, btw: http://osstatus.com

Comment: Regarding the crashing issue, I should have been more specific; it will crash if you encounter a file which is corrupt in a way that `Data(base64Encoded:options:)` cannot parse. If the Base64 can be decoded but the file format cannot be read after that, then you'll get an error rather than a crash (as you're seeing). You're checking it against `nil` later anyway, so just replace that check, and the declaration, with an `if let` statement and it'll be much cleaner in addition to being more correct.

Comment: Postfix `!` in Swift basically means "I'm promising this will never be `nil`; if I'm wrong and `nil` shows up here, crash."

Comment: Ok thanks that makes since. I will defiantly make that change, so what do you suggest I do to get the files to be albe to be read with AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Without knowing what the format of the files is, that's hard for me to answer. You could play the files using something other than `AVAudioPlayer` which supports that file type, or if you have control of the server, you could convert the files there to a format that `AVAudioPlayer` knows how to read.

Comment: OK, do you know any other pods or frameworks that can be used to play various types of audio files in formats like base64? or what kind of conversions are out there

Comment: I don't even know what format your files are in, so... no.